# How I can send image to GCP Vision API

Tags: java, android, json, api, google-cloud-platform

Im going to use Google Cloud Vision API.

In tutorial it says that I need to send the image to their Google Cloud Storage and after that by using that link I need to make a request to API.
So the scheme looks like this:

Phone photo(Local Storage) ***--download--> GC Storage --get link-->*** Send request with this link to GC Vision API --get JSON--> work with JSON

So the question is.
What for I need to storage image in cloud? Only for a link? Can I send the image direct to the Vision API without GC Storage?
So the scheme:

**Phone photo(Local Storage) --download-->to GC Vision API --get JSON--> work with JSON**

Comment: See  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/vision/label/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/vision/samples/label/LabelApp.java

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you can send an image directly to the vision API as below:

```
package code.logicbeat.vision.controller;

import java.util.Collections;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.util.StreamUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.AnnotateImageRequest;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.AnnotateImageResponse;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.BatchAnnotateImagesResponse;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.Feature;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.Image;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotatorClient;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
@RestController
public class VisionController {

    @Autowired
    private ImageAnnotatorClient imageAnnotatorClient;

    @PostMapping("/vision")
    public String uploadImage(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {

        byte[] imageBytes = StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(file.getInputStream());
        Image image = Image.newBuilder().setContent(ByteString.copyFrom(imageBytes)).build();

        // Sets the type of request to label detection, to detect broad sets of
        // categories in an image.
        Feature feature = Feature.newBuilder().setType(Feature.Type.LABEL_DETECTION).build();
        AnnotateImageRequest request = AnnotateImageRequest.newBuilder().setImage(image).addFeatures(feature).build();
        BatchAnnotateImagesResponse responses = this.imageAnnotatorClient
            .batchAnnotateImages(Collections.singletonList(request));
        StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder("<table border=\"1\">");
        responseBuilder.append("<tr><th>description</th><th>score</th></tr>");
        // We're only expecting one response.
        if (responses.getResponsesCount() == 1) {
            AnnotateImageResponse response = responses.getResponses(0);
            if (response.hasError()) {
                System.out.println(response.getError());
                throw new Exception(response.getError().getMessage());
            }

            for (EntityAnnotation annotation : response.getLabelAnnotationsList()) {
                responseBuilder.append("<tr><td>").append(annotation.getDescription()).append("</td><td>")
                    .append(annotation.getScore()).append("</td></tr>");
            }
        }
        responseBuilder.append("</table>");
        return responseBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Please check the link to my repo example for reference:
https://github.com/logicbeat/googlevisionapidemo

Also, you can check this link:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/vision/label/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/vision/samples/label/LabelApp.java